# How do I append more compressed data to Inflater?

Tags: java, zlib, randomaccessfile

It seems that setInput doesn't append the data in the Inflater object.

Context:
I have a RandomAccessFile object where I am trying to read in 1024 byte blocks and am trying to append the data to an Inflater.

Example of what I was trying to do:

```
while(compressedSize > 0) {
  int size = Math.min(1024, compressedSize);
  raf.readFully(buf, 0, 1024);
  inflater.setInput(buf, 0, size); // want to append buf to inflater, not set
}

while(! inflater.finished()) {
  int size = inflater.inflate(buf);
  outputStream.write(buf, 0, size);
}
```

Comment: Please, show your code where the problem is.

Comment: I have added an example of what I am trying to do. What I want setInput to do is append the remaining compressed data to whatever buffer it has, but it isn't doing it.

Comment: Take a look at this link http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-compress-and-uncompress. You might also want to use needsInput() to refill the inflater buffer. Or, if you want to stream it, maybe use an InflaterInputStream instead.